# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, recursion with random numbers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, recursion, infinite-loop

So I know max call stack error is appearing when infinite loop is in occurring, by recursion. But I'm having this weird problem. Everything in code under works fine, until I add these 2 commented lines under randomRow and randomCol. Is it possible to create infinite loop with random numbers or am I missing something?

```
function insertNumbers(freeRCPos, grid, fields, num) {
//base case
if (fields.length === 0) return grid;


let randomRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxRows);
let randomCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxRows);
// if (grid[randomRow][randomCol].value !== undefined)
//   return insertNumbers(freeRCPos, grid, fields, num);

let newFields = [];
//there are in total 9 fields so it has to go through all of them  
for (let field of fields) {
//check if its already in field
if (field.includes(JSON.stringify([randomRow, randomCol]))) {
  let res = freeRCPos.map((element: any) =>
    element.map((pos: any) =>
      pos === JSON.stringify([randomRow, randomCol]) ? true : false
    )
  );
  if (
    res.filter((el: any) => (el.includes(true) ? true : false)).length > 0
  ) {
    grid[randomRow][randomCol].value = num;
    newFields= fields.filter(
      (_: any, fieldId: number) => fields.indexOf(field) !== fieldId
    );
    //return with modified fields and others to be able to complete base case
    return insertNumbers(
      freeRCPos.map((field: any) =>
        field.map((pos: string) =>
          pos?.startsWith("[" + randomRow) || pos?.endsWith(randomCol + "]")
            ? null
            : pos
        )
      ),
      grid,
      newFields,
      num,
    );
  //else return same
  } else {
    return insertNumbers(freeRCPos, grid, fields, num);
  }
//else return same
} else {
  return insertNumbers(freeRCPos, grid, fields, num);
}
}
return grid;
}
```

I've maybe put a lot of unnecessary code here so if I need to shorten it, just ask. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the random numbers are the existing indexes in `grid` (= if `grid[randomRow][randomCol].value !== undefined` is true), it will never pass the commented part and it will keep calling itself with the same values. You need to update something before calling the function recursively and get closer to the base case which is `fields.length === 0`.

Comment: But when it gets called again, randomRow and randomCol change. So, it will create new randomRow and Col and it will check again and around like that, right?

Comment: Correct. The question is where it should stop calling itself? As long as `grid[randomRow][randomCol].value` is not undefined, it keeps calling. Because `randomRow` and `randomCol` are always valid, if-condition is always true. You should have a base case before calling again, so that at some point, it will stop.

Comment: I'm getting little confused right now, but I get the idea. I thought it would be enough to add it as another condition in if state. Can u tell me how would u approach this because honestly have no idea. appreciate the help

Comment: Please tell us more about the goal, the parameters, the input, and the expected outputs.

Comment: if value is undefined, new value should be inserted, else value exists - repeat (numbers are not good). So I just need to control those random numbers I get somehow,  I suppose. Inputs: grid: 2d array with values, num is value that should be inserted as a value and other two are just arrays of cell places where values can be added (on each call they change). Output should just be grid when the values are/aren't changed.

Comment: Sorry that it is not clear enough for me. If you have a 'grid' and know the 'free'/editable positions, no need to use recursion. Just loop through the free positions and (over)write the items. Sample inputs would make this question clearer.

Comment: Lets think simple. There is just one condition: those 2 commented lines up there. If is not undefined return recursion else return grid. How would u create base case for those random numbers? (myb passing numbers as params?)